# Indices simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question asks me to simplify each of the following, leaving each with positive indices. 
I don't understand the question.

$$(\frac{3x^{-1}y^2z^{-2}}{5x^{-2}y^{-2}z^2})^{-1}(\frac{6x^{-2}y^0z^{-1}}{20x^{-3}y^2z})^2$$

Can anyone give me some guides?

Comment: Indices or powers?

Comment: @crash what you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note the following:
$$
\left(\frac{3x^{-1}y^2z^{-2}}{5x^{-2}y^{-2}z^2}\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac{5x^{-2}y^{-2}z^2}{3x^{-1}y^2z^{-2}}\right)=\left(\frac{5z^4}{3xy^4}\right).
$$
Then note the following:
$$
\left(\frac{6x^{-2}y^0z^{-1}}{20x^{-3}y^2z}\right)^2=\left(\frac{6x}{20y^2z^2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{36x^2}{400y^4z^4}\right)
$$
Thus, we have that
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{3x^{-1}y^2z^{-2}}{5x^{-2}y^{-2}z^2}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(\frac{6x^{-2}y^0z^{-1}}{20x^{-3}y^2z}\right)^2 &= \left(\frac{5z^4}{3xy^4}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{36x^2}{400y^4z^4}\right)\\[1em]
&= \left(\frac{180x^2z^4}{1200xy^8z^4}\right)\\[1em]
&= \frac{3}{20}\left(\frac{x}{y^8}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quite a time didn't do this kind of algebra question. Hahah. Anyway, thanks.